# Measurable maps in metric spaces.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have several questions about measurability of maps with values in metric spaces.

1. When $X$ and $Y$ are two separable metric spaces, it is easy to prove that $\mathcal{B}(X\times Y) = \mathcal{B}(X)\otimes \mathcal{B}(Y)$ (Borel sigma fields). Does it still hold when $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces but not separable?
2. If the answer to 1. is negative is it true however that if $X$ is a metric space ($d$ the related distance) which is not separable $$\{(x,y)\in X\times X : x= y\}$$ is measurable?
3. If the answer to 1. is negative, and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is some probability space,  $r>0$, is it true however that if $X$ is a metric space (neither complete nor separable), and $f,g : \Omega \to X$ are two measurable maps (for $\mathcal{F}$ and the Borel sigma field) then $\{\omega \in \Omega | d(f(\omega), g(\omega)) > r\}$ is measurable?
4. If $X$ is a metric space which is not complete. And $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable map $f_n : \Omega \to X$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space, is the set of the $\omega$ on which $(f_n)$ converges measurable?

Thank you.

Comment: Too many questions in the same post...